# Unable to resize C partition windows 8

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning

I would like to shrink my main Windows 8 partition to allow for a dual boot. If I go to Disk Manager and right click on any other drive, I get options to shrink/change the drive, but when I click on my C partition, I just get an empty context menu with "Help". (See images below)

I haven't seen anyone else get this problem online? Does anyone know why it could be happening?

I tried to boot into Linux on an external drive and shrink the partition from there, but the process hung and it ended up corrupting my C drive. I had to restore Windows.

I'm on windows 8.1 x64. It's a Razor Blade laptop.

Thanks for any help!

[image: Works fine for other drives]

[image: No option to resize C:]

Comment: This cannot be done without third-party software.  Why was your other question deleted?  You do understand your already at your partition maximum on that disk though right?  You would need to use GPT instead, which means, you would have to install Windows again.